# Reversal Testing for Financial Postings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I edited my questions as I did not receive an answer which solves my problem which because I was not specific enough.

I am analyzing financial postings from SAP. I have the data on a SQL server and I run various analyses on those financial postings.

I also need to do a so called "reversal testing". This means that I need to find postings that are the exact opposite of the one I have. I will make an example so that it becomes clear.

My starting table is the following:

```
Document Nr.  Amount  Debit or Credit  Account
1001          100     Credit           9999  
1001          100     Credit           8888  
1001          200     Debit            7777  
1002          50      Credit           2222  
1002          50      Debit            1111  
1003          100     Debit            9999  
1003          100     Debit            8888  
1003          200     Credit           7777  
1004          100     Debit            9999  
1004          100     Credit           7777
```

Now I have to find opposite document numbers. This means the same amounts on the same accounts with the opposite debit or credit indicators per document number. In the example above 1001 and 1003 are reversals of each other so I need to find them.

Does anyone know how to find this with an SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Will a document contain only credits or debits, or can it be a mix of both?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select documentnumber,
       (case when dc_indicator = 'Credit' then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end) as dc_indicator, amount, account
from t;
```

This would generate the results that you specify.

Comment: Hi Gordon

Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately I saw that I made a mistake in the question. The second table has of course a different document number because we are looking for other documents with the same amounts but interchanged debit / credit postings on the same accounts.

Comment: I changed the question so I hope now it is clear what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self JOIN:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM document_table t1
    INNER JOIN document_table t2
        ON t1.Document_Number <> t2.Document_Number
AND t1.[Debit or Credit Indicator] = 'Debit'
AND t2.[Debit or Credit Indicator] = 'Credit'
AND t1.Amount = t2.Amount
AND t1.Account = t2.Account
```

Comment: Hi Serge

Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately I saw that I made a mistake in the question. The second table has of course a different document number because we are looking for other documents with the same amounts but interchanged debit / credit postings on the same accounts.

Comment: You want to find reverals in **different** documents? Or the document doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi Serge
The document number has to be different. Because every document is unique so there should not be a hit for the same document number with different credit / debit postings. So the goal is basically to find other documents that have the opposite credit/debit bookings.

Comment: Then you need to change `=` to `<>` in the `ON t1.Document_Number <> t2.Document_Number` clause of the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hi Serge 
Thank you for quick response. I tried the query but the issue is that it gives me results from different other document numbers which match the criteria. For example this is one of the outcomes:
 
1003|Credit|200|70500, 

1004|Debit|100|50800, 

1003|Debit|100|10400, 
 
1005|Debit|100|10400, 


The query looks for single values that are reversals. What I am looking for is documents which are reversal of other documents. So the resulting document must contain all lines for the reversal and it can't be a mix of different other documents.

Comment: I also edited the question again. I hope now it is clear what I am looking for.